# Chart data not exporting completely

Tags: javascript, user-interface, charts, export, webix

I am trying to export a dataset from the chart, one of the lines should be started from the second x-axis point. I.e. dataset looks like

```
var dataset = [
  {           dept2:26, m:"Jan" },
  { dept1:30, dept2:38, m:"Feb" },
  { dept1:61, dept2:54, m:"Mar" },
  { dept1:65, dept2:67, m:"Apr" },
  { dept1:74, dept2:69, m:"May" },
  { dept1:74, dept2:69, m:"Jun" },
  { dept1:74, dept2:69, m:"Jul" }

];
```

Full snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/457ffa4e

But toExcel method in Webix won't export column without the first value. How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define your output in this way:

```
    webix.toExcel($$("chart"), {
      columns:{
        "dept1":true,
        "dept2":true,
        "m":true
      }
    });
```

[**Snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/cbb5782b)